# Change dropdown based on another dropdown in Angular 11?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to change dropdown based on another dropdown.

ts.file

```
     Countries: Array<any> = [
                { name: '1st of the month', states: [ {name: '16th of the month'} ] },
                { name: '2nd of the month', states: [ {name: '17th of the month'} ] },
                { name: '3rd of the month', states: [ {name: '18th of the month'} ] },
                             ]
    
     states: Array<any> = []; 
     cities: Array<any> = []; 
    
     changeCountry(country: any) { 
            this.states = this.Countries.find(cntry => cntry.name == country.target.value).states; 
        }
```

html.file

```
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select  [(ngModel)]="custFirst"  name="custFirst" placeholder="Country"  (change)="changeCountry($event)">
               <mat-option   *ngFor="let country of Countries" [value]="country.name" > {{ country.name }}</mat-option> 
         </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
            
    <mat-form-field>
          <mat-select placeholder="State">
             <mat-option *ngFor="let state of states"  [value]="state.name">{{ state.name }} 
             </mat-option>
           </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Now my problem is that, I unable to get the value in second dropdown. Please help me why trigger part is not working.

[image: here is the picture of dropdowns]

Comment: Do you want to autopopulate the value selected in second dropdown based on first one?

Comment: yes deepakchethan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `change` event should be changed to `selectionChange`. If you want the state to be auto-selected add `[(ngModel)]` to the state dropdown and update it when the country is changed:

```
 changeCountry(country: any) { 
    this.states = this.Countries.find(
      (cntry) => cntry.name == country.value
    ).states;
    this.sFirst = this.states[0].name;
 }
```

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select  [(ngModel)]="custFirst"  name="custFirst" placeholder="Country" (selectionChange)="changeCountry($event)">
           <mat-option   *ngFor="let country of Countries" [value]="country.name" > {{ country.name }}</mat-option> 
     </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
        
<mat-form-field>
      <mat-select placeholder="State" [(ngModel)]="stateFirst">
         <mat-option *ngFor="let state of states"  [value]="state.name">{{ state.name }} 
         </mat-option>
       </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-stackoverflow-nzvqse?file=src/app/components/stackoverflow-solution/stackoverflow-solution.component.ts

Comment: After selecting country dropdown , it should trigger changecountry function but in my case trigger is not happening .

Comment: @MohamedIrshath Can you change `(change)` to `(selectionChange)` and try?

Comment: it throws error " Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')" @deepak

Comment: @MohamedIrshath, Please update the changeCountry method as well as per the latest edit

Comment: its working . my scenario i shouldn't click the state dropdown . is there any way like clicking the first dropdown with same value and related value should pop up in the state dropdown field @deepakchethan

Comment: @MohamedIrshath. Please see the latest update or the stackblitz. You will have to update two way binded variable `this.sFirst = this.states[0].name;` in `countryChange`

Answer (score 0):

You can handle that with a switch case statements, pass the value of country to the function getStates

```js
country:string = 'Uruguay';
states:string[];

getStates(country: string){
   switch(country) {
      case '':
        this.states = [];
        break;
      case 'República Dominicana':
        this.states = ['', 'Azua', 'Baoruco', 'Barahona', 'Valverde'];
        break;
      case 'Uruguay':
        this.states = ['', 'Artigas', 'Canelones', 'Tacuarembó'];
        break;
      case 'Venezuela':
        this.states = ['', 'Amazonas', 'Apure', 'Yaracuy'];
        break;            
   }
}

this.getCountryData(this.country);
```

then in view:

```js
 <mat-option *ngFor="let state of states"  [value]="state.name">{{ state.name }}
```

Comment: I unable to get your point . please more specific

Comment: You can have two array variables: countries and states, you can first create a dropdown based on countries variable, and call a function (getStates) that updates the states variable

Comment: then you can create another dropdown based on states array variable